# ANTLR: Lexer RULE does not match

Tags: antlr4

I want to match the following text:
*test.define_shared_constant(:testConst, "12", false)*

With this grammar it matches correctly:

```
grammar test;

statement: shared_constant_defioniton | method_call;
KEY: ':' ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_'|'?'|'!'|'|'|'-'|'()')+;
expr: STRING;
STRING: '"' (~'"')* ('"' | NEWLINE) | '\'' (~'\'')* ('\'' | NEWLINE);
NEWLINE: '\r'? '\n' | '\r'; 
BOOLEAN: 'true' | 'false';
ID: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'!') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_'|'!'|'?')*;
WS : [ \t\n\r]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
DEF_SHARED_CONSTANT: 'define_shared_constant';

shared_constant_defioniton
  : ID('.define_shared_constant' '(' KEY ',' expr ',' (BOOLEAN) ')')
;

method_call
  : ID '.' ID? '('expr*(',' expr)*')'
;
```

With this grammar it does not match. It matches to method_call which is not even correct.

```
 shared_constant_defioniton
  : ID('.' DEF_SHARED_CONSTANT '(' KEY ',' expr ',' (BOOLEAN) ')')
;
```

It is interpreting 'define_shared_constant' as ID. So I have to specify that ID should not contain 'define_'. But how can I do that?

Comment: You have a mismatched single quote in the grammar rule that supposedly works--it's not valid Antlr. Please correct the syntax.

Comment: Please add enough of your grammar so that others can reproduce what you describe. If the grammar is not hundreds of lines long, just add the entire grammar.

Comment: There's no way that `define_sharedConstant` works with either of your grammars (even ignoring the syntax error in the first one), so I'm assuming you meant `define_shared_constant`. With that change your input works fine on the second grammar, if I fill in the blanks. So please post a [MCVE] that properly reproduces the problem.

Comment: Sorry, the mismatched single quote in the first grammer was a typo. both ('.' 'define_shared_constant'... and ('.define_shared_constant'....) work. As soon as I move 'define_shared_constant' to a LEXER rule it stops matching.

You can omit  the rules between the braces it still behaves the same. But here you have the complete grammar:

Comment: No problem @user39558, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ID: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'!') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_'|'!'|'?')*;
WS : [ \t\n\r]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
DEF_SHARED_CONSTANT: 'define_shared_constant';
```

Here both `ID` and `DEF_SHARED_CONSTANT` could match the input `define_shared_constant`. In cases like this where multiple rules could match and would produce a match of the same length, the rule that's defined first wins. So `defined_shared_constant` is recognized as an `ID` token because `ID` is defined first.

To get the behaviour you want, you should move the definition of `DEF_SHARED_CONSTANT` before the definition of `ID`. If you don't define a named lexer rule for it at all and instead use `'define_shared_constant'` directly in the parser rule, that also works because implicitly defined lexer rules act as if they had been defined at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

This worked according to ANTLR specification. But running it as an IntelliJ Language plugin did not. I had use a predicated and the final solution looks like this:

```
ID: { getText().indexOf("define") == 0}? ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'!') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_'|'!'|'?')*;
```